# Proof check: $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

Is my proof of the following statement valid? Any feedback is welcome. Thank you in advance.

> $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

*Proof.* We break the proof into two cases: (case 1) $a > 0$ and (case 2) $a = 0$.

(case 1) Suppose $a > 0$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\delta = \min\{a, \epsilon^2\} > 0$.
\begin{align} 
0 < |x - a| < \delta &\implies a - \delta < x < a + \delta \\ 
&\implies \sqrt{a - \delta} < \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{a + \delta} \qquad \text{(by Lemma 1 below and $(a - \delta) \geq 0 $ because $\delta = \min\{a, \epsilon^2\}$)} \\
&\implies \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{\delta} < \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{\delta} \qquad \text{(by Lemma 2 below)} \\
&\implies -\sqrt{\delta} < \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a} < \sqrt{\delta} \\
&\implies |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \sqrt{\delta} \leq \sqrt{\epsilon^2} \\
&\implies |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \epsilon \\
&\implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon.
\end{align}
This proves that $f$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$.

(case 2) Suppose $a = 0$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\delta = \epsilon^2 > 0$.
\begin{align} 
0 < |x - a| < \delta &\implies 0 < |x| < \delta \\ 
&\implies 0 < x < \delta \\
&\implies \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{\delta} = \sqrt{\epsilon^2} \qquad \text{(by Lemma 1 below)}\\
&\implies \sqrt{x} < \epsilon \\
&\implies |\sqrt{x} - 0| < \epsilon \\
&\implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon.
\end{align}
This proves that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Therefore, $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$. $\square$

> Lemma 1. If $0 \leq a < b$, then $\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b}$.

*Proof.* (Lemma 1) We will prove by contradiction. Suppose $0 \leq a < b$ and $\sqrt{a} \geq \sqrt{b}$. Since $\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b} \geq 0$ by definition, multiplying both sides of $\sqrt{a} \geq \sqrt{b}$ by $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ respectively gives us the following.
$$ (a \geq \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b} \quad \text{and} \quad \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b} \geq b) \implies a \geq b \quad \textbf{contradiction!} \square $$

> Lemma 2. If $a, b > 0$, then $\sqrt{a + b} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$.

*Proof.* (Lemma 2) By the triangle inequality we have the following.
\begin{align}
|\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}| \leq |\sqrt{a}| + |\sqrt{b}| &\implies \sqrt{(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2} \leq \sqrt{(\sqrt{a})^2} + \sqrt{(\sqrt{b})^2} \\
&\implies  \sqrt{a + b} \leq \sqrt{a + 2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} + b} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} \\
&\implies \sqrt{a + b} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}. \square
\end{align}

Comment: You are missing an important proof, for the fact that $\sqrt{a-\delta}\geq\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{\delta}$. This does not follow from Lemma 2, but you are using it in line $3$ of your proof.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim It follows from Lemma 2. Let $a  = a - \delta$, $b = \delta$, then move $\sqrt{b}$ to the other side.

Comment: Ah, you are completely right. Nevertheless, given the degree of detail elsewhere in the proof, I would include such a comment, i.e. how you apply Lemma 2 in this case, in the proof. Other than that, everything looks fine.

Comment: The $\delta$ you use in Case 1 depends on $a$ (and tends to 0 as $a\to 0$), therefore this doesn't give you uniform continuity. One way to fix this is to use Lemma 2 to prove $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq \sqrt{|x-y|}$ for all $x,y\geq 0$ (you use this implicitly in the line @SomeCallMeTim mentioned). Then use $\delta=\varepsilon^2$.